# Hardcoding current path to alias

Tags: command-line, fish

I am developing a simple cli-application for timetracking. The idea is to have fish-aliases source r-scripts to create timestamps in a timetable. Like so:

`alias checkin='rscript (echo $PWD/checkin.R)'`

However writing it like this only allows me to call the alias if I am standing in the correct directory. Is there a way for me to hardcode the current path, so I can call it from any directory?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand the flow.  Does that `rscript (echo $PWD/checkin.R)` work from any directory when *not* in an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes are the problem. They [prevent variable expansion](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#quotes).

If you want to use the PWD when you **define** the alias, use double quotes:

```sh
cd /the/wanted/directory
alias checkin "rscript $PWD/checkin.R"
```

(the = is optional)

See how it is defined: `type checkin`

Then `funcsave checkin` to save the function (which the alias creates) permanently with the correct path.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve my problem!

Comment: Note: This will be broken if the current directory contains spaces or any special characters - to alias they'll look like separate arguments. It's probably much nicer to define an actual function and use `--inherit-variable` to inherit the value.